# Configure langs in Laravel Translatable BootForms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to [Laravel Translatable BootForms](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Translatable-Bootforms), and I was wondering something.

When I use this code :

```
{!!
    TranslatableBootForm::text('Nom', 'name')
        ->required()
!!}
```

The render is as follows :

[image: A list of languages I don't remember having configured]

I don't know where this language list comes from.

I only want to list some languages specified in my database, as I do with this workaround :

```
@foreach($availableLangs as $availableLang)
    {!!
        TranslatableBootForm::text('Nom', 'name')
        ->renderLocale($availableLang['locale'])
    !!}
@endforeach
```

Which gives me this :

[image: The intended render]

My two questions are :

- Where does this language list come from ?
- How can I replace it by my own language list ?

Answering the first question may lead to an automatic answer for the second, though)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you should always try to read the Service Providers, they provide important clues about the project structures. Let's try to follow the trail of the function calls:

`TranslatableBootForm` is a facade and it resolves to and instance of `translatable-bootform` from the Service Container according to this line:

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'translatable-bootform'; }
```

Now, in the file `TranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider.php` we can see that `translatable-bootform` is an instance of `TranslatableBootForm`. So when you call `TranslatableBootForm::text`, you will be using the `Facade` which resolves to an instance of `TranslatableBootForm`

Opening the `TranslatableBootForm` class, we cannot find the `text` method, so there should be a `__call` method. The `__call` method always returns whatever is returned from the method `render`. So that's where the action is happening.

Reading the code there, you will find that it gets the locales from a method called `locales` and it will intersect it with the `func_get_args()` function to get whatever languages you pass to it. So `renderLocale` or simply `render` will do the same thing.

The method `locales` just returns an array which is by default empty in the class. If we return back to the `TranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider` we will see that there's an important line:

```
$formBuilder->setLocales($this->getLocales());
```

Which gets the locales from `Translatable\TranslatableWrapper` which is just a wrapper around this file in another package: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/Translatable/Translatable.php

Looking at the configuration file in the `laravel-translatable` package, we can see the languages:
https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/config/translatable.php

#### Solutions

Now, you can simply copy the file `translatable.php` in your `config` folder and set your locales.

Or, you create a new service provider `MyTranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider`

```
class MyTranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider extends TranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider 
{

    /**
     * Get Translatable's locales.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLocales()
    {
        // You can return a config key
        // return config('yourconfig.locales');
        // Or directly the array containing the languages
        return ['en', 'fr', 'nl'];

    }
}
```

Then, you will use this provider in your `config/app.php` instead of the original `TranslatableBootFormsServiceProvider`

Disclaimer:
I didn't try the code, you might have a bug, but you get the idea now how to find your way around Laravel packages.